# How to mock a factory static method in order to return a mocked object?

Tags: mocking, pytest, static-methods

I have the following class:

```py
class Toto():

    @staticmethod
    def factory():
        return Toto("Toto")

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    @staticmethod
    def method_to_test():
      # do stuff
      toto_object = Toto.factory()
      # do stuff with toto_object
      toto_object.get_name()
```

I want to `mock` the `factory` method of `Toto` so when it's called, it returns a mock of `Toto`.

The following test should then pass:

```py
from junit.toto import Toto


def test_toto_method_to_test(mocked):
    mocked_toto = mocker.patch("junit.toto.Toto")
    mocked_toto.get_name.return_value = "Tata"
    mocked_toto_factory = mocker.patch(__name__ + ".Toto.factory")
    mocked_toto_factory.return_value = mocked_junit_xml_generator

    Toto.method_to_test()
    mocked_toto.get_name.assert_called()

    #mocked_toto and mock in the tested method are not the same -> FAIL
```

Currently, I fail to properly mock the factory method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your test, you don't use the mocked instance of `Toto`, which resides in the `Toto` module, but the one imported in the test itself (`from ... import Toto`). To fix this, there are 2 possibilities: use the mocked object, or mock the reference in the test itself.

To use the mocked object, you shall import the module containing the object to be mocked:

```py
import junit

def test_toto_mock(mocker):
    mocked_toto = mocker.patch("junit.toto.Toto")
    mocked_toto.get_name.return_value = "Tata"

    assert mocked_toto.get_name() == "Tata"

    mocked_toto.factory.return_value = mocked_toto

    # use the same reference that you have mocked
    assert junit.toto.Toto.factory().get_name() == "Tata"
```

If you import the object using `from ... import`, you have to patch the reference in the test module instead, with `__name__` containing the name of the current module:

```py
from junit.toto import ToTo

def test_toto_mock(mocker):
    # mock the reference in the test itself
    mocked_toto = mocker.patch(__name__ + ".Toto")
    mocked_toto.get_name.return_value = "Tata"

    assert mocked_toto.get_name() == "Tata"

    mocked_toto.factory.return_value = mocked_toto
    # use the local reference of ToTo
    assert Toto.factory().get_name() == "Tata"
```

If for some reason you need to mock both instances, as mentioned in the comments, you can also do this:

```py
import junit
from junit.toto import ToTo

def test_toto_mock(mocker):
    mocked_toto = mocker.patch(__name__ + ".Toto")
    # replace the object in the other module with the same mock
    mocker.patch("junit.toto.Toto", mocked_toto)
    mocked_toto.get_name.return_value = "Tata"

    assert mocked_toto.get_name() == "Tata"

    mocked_toto.factory.return_value = mocked_toto

    assert Toto.factory().get_name() == "Tata"
    assert junit.toto.Toto.factory().get_name() == "Tata"
```

Please read [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6) for more information.

Comment: Mocking the reference from the test itself is a great idea, however it does not work in my case, I updated the initial post to better reflect the issue. I am now trying your first proposition but I think I will have the same issue.

Comment: I do not know if this is the best solution, but I solved the issue by mocking BOTH class. So either when I call the factory from the test, or from Toto, I get the same mocked object. If you update your post I will mark it as answer

Comment: Ok, I adapted the previous examples to be less complicated (only need to patch once), and added another one which shows how to patch both references.